# Failure attempting to launch in Bitrise iOS build expired token

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bitrise

I'm using Bitrise as a CI solution, unfortunately when starting the UITests the logs are telling me.

> Failure attempting to launch in Bitrise iOS build Expired token: no
>   operation still exists for this token.

The unit tests are working fine. Not sure why this is happening. The simulator seems to start normally.

Of course launch is called is inside of `setUp()`

```swift
override func setUp() {
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
    continueAfterFailure = false

    // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
    // Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
    XCUIApplication().launch()

    // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation -
    // required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
}
```

The Apple Documentation is saying for `launch()`

> This call is synchronous. When it returns, the application is launched
>   and ready to handle user events. Any failure in the launch sequence is
>   reported as a test failure and halts the test at this point.

So it should work fine as the simulator should start first before running the tests.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue when tests executes from Jenkins/fastlane. Did u find any solution ? any help is really appreciated.